# Section script is not being read in my view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code where I am trying to disable all links in my view if the status is one. However when I run my code it just skips over the whole section script view which has my Jquery inside. What can I do so that it does read my code?

```
@model IEnumerable<RiAct._02.Models.ModelRisk>

@{
    List<RiAct._02.Models.ModelRisk> list = new List<RiAct._02.Models.ModelRisk>();
    foreach (var m in Model)
    {
        list.Add(m);
    }
    int status = 0;
    if (list.Count() > 0)
    {
        RiAct._02.Models.ModelRisk risk = list.First();
        status = Convert.ToInt32(risk.ModelProcess.Status);
    }
    <h1>status is @status</h1>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CustomJquery.js")"></script>
    @if (status != 1)
    {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            function DisableFeatures() {
                $("a").prop('disabled', true).css('color', "gray");
            }
            DisableFeatures();
            });
        </script>
    }
    else
    {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            function EnableFeatures() {
                $("a").prop('disabled', false).css('color', "#2fa4e7");
            }
            EnableFeatures();
            });
        </script>
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `RenderSection("Scripts")` call in the layout ?

Comment: what do you have in _layout.cshtml? you need  @if IsSectionDefined("Scripts")) { @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false) }

Comment: It didn't seem to help, I have RenderSection("Scripts") in my layout and also tried to put @if( IsSectionDefined("Scripts")) { @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false) } , but it didn't make a differnce. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is this a partial view?

Comment: Yes it is a partial view

Comment: try putting the script into the parent view then

Comment: Thank you so much. That was a great help!

Comment: Razor sections are ignored in partial views. Razor processes sections before it processes partials, so there's no way to hook into that process from a partial: two entirely different scopes.

Comment: I am having the same problem that the code is not reaching my section scrips  but this time it is not in a partial view, but in a regular view.

Comment: It does work in a regular view, i was just missing quotes in one line of code, so that messed it up.